# Laravel: Pass Variables in View to Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to pass two variables from the form in the view to my controller and there to use them...

How to do this?

---

### shop.blade.php:

```
<div class="mcitem">
                    <img src="/images/shop/Stein.png" alt="Stein">
                    <div class="mcunits">
                        {{ Form::open(array('action' => 'ShopController@add', $itemid, $bprice)) }}
                        {{ Form::number('units', '0') }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="mcbuy">
                        $itemid = 1;
                        $bprice = 3;
                        {{ Form::submit('3,00 Coins', array('name' => 'buybtn')) }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="mcsell">
                        {{ Form::submit('1,00 Coin', array('name' => 'sellbtn', $itemid='1', $sprice=1)) }}
                        {{ Form::close() }}
                    </div>
                </div>
```

### ShopController:

```
public function add(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'units' => 'required|min:1',
    ]);
    if(Input::Get('buybtn')) {
        $this->Buy(); //if Buy Button is pushed
    } elseif(Input::Get('sellbtn')) {
        $this->Sell(); //if Sell Button is pushed
    }
}

public function Buy(){
    $username = Auth::user()->name;
    $units = Input::Get('units');
    if((DB::table('users')->where('name', $username)->value('kontostand')) >= ($bprice*$units)){
        $check_entry = DB::table($username)->where('Item', '=', $itemid)->first();
        if(is_null($check_entry)){
            $hunits = DB::table($username)->where('Item', $itemid)->select('units')->get();
            DB::table($username)->where('Item', $itemid)->update([$itemid => $hunits + $units]);
        }
        else{
            DB::table($username)->where('Item', $itemid)->insert(
                [$itemid => $units]
            );
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "Zu wenig Geld auf dem Kontostand!";
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `{!! Form::hidden() !!}` field

Answer (score 0):

Use hidden field

```
<div class="mcitem">
    <img src="/images/shop/Stein.png" alt="Stein">
    {!! Form::open(array('action' => 'ShopController@add')) !!}
    <div class="mcunits">
        {!! Form::number('units', '0') !!}
    </div>
    <div class="mcbuy">
        {!! Form::hidden('itemid', '1') !!}
        {!! Form::hidden('bprice', '3') !!}
        {!! Form::submit('3,00 Coins', array('name' => 'buybtn')) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="mcsell">
        {!! Form::submit('1,00 Coin', array('name' => 'sellbtn')) !!}
    </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

Controller

`$request->get('itemid);`....

Comment: add `dd($request->all()` after validation check, add check itemid is in there. also use 'Input::get()` instead of `Input::Get()`

Comment: and also remove two variables from submit button.(see my updated answer)

Comment: it's values on hidden fields, value must be string

Comment: can you see itemid on `dd($request->all());`?

Comment: don't know what you mean...do i need the variables here? {!! Form::open(array('action' => 'ShopController@add', $itemid, $bprice)) !!}

Comment: no, you don't want those, sorry I forgot remove from my answer

Comment: if it doesn't fix the error, try to find line number of error from stack trace

Comment: the problem now is here DB::table($username)->where('Item', $itemid)->update($itemid => $hunits + $units);

Comment: I can't understand your query. according to this if username is "john" you should have a table "john" and you are trying to update value for column name "1"(if itemid=1) where column "Item" equals to 1. If that's what you want to do, what's the error?

Comment: Yeah I think so...
I have to columns: Item and units.. So I want to update the unitsfield where Item is itemid..

`Item     Units
1             5`

The command should update that field units:
`Item     Units
1             10`

Comment: `DB::table($username)->where('Item', $itemid)->update(['units' => $hunits + $units]);`

Comment: Unsupported operand types

Comment: try `$hunits = DB::table($username)->where('Item', $itemid)->select('units')->first(); $hunits=(is_null($hunits))?0:$hunits->units; DB::table($username)->where('Item', $itemid)->update(['units' => (int)$hunits + $units]); `

Comment: No error but no entry. I think this one is false:

else{
    DB::table($username)->where('Item', $itemid)->insert([$itemid => $units]);
   }

Comment: for insert and update you need to pass `[column_name => value]` array. Please read this for more info https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries

Comment: DB::table($username)->insert(['Item' => $itemid, 'units' => $units]);

No entry...

Comment: where did you defined $itemid, I can't see that on you code. Please update your question with you current code

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="mcunits">
    {{ Form::open(array('action' => 'ShopController@add')) }}
    {{ Form::number('units', '0') }}
    {{ Form::hidden('itemid', 1) }}
    {{ Form::hidden('bprice', 3) }}
</div>
<div class="mcbuy">
    {{ Form::submit('3,00 Coins', array('name' => 'buybtn')) }}
</div>

$itemid = Input::Get('itemid');
$bprice = Input::Get('bprice');
```

Resolves following error: Unsupported operand types

Comment: change `{{ Form::hidden('itemid', 1) }}` to `{{ Form::hidden('itemid', '1') }}`

Answer (score 0):

ShopController:

```
public function add(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'units' => 'required|min:1',
    ]);
    if(Input::Get('buybtn')) {
        $this->Buy(); //if Buy Button is pushed
    } elseif(Input::Get('sellbtn')) {
        $this->Sell(); //if Sell Button is pushed
    }
    return view('shop');
}

public function Buy(){
    $username = Auth::user()->name;
    $units = Input::Get('units');
    $itemid = Input::Get('itemid');
    $bprice = Input::Get('bprice');
    if((DB::table('users')->where('name', $username)->value('kontostand')) >= ($bprice*$units)){
        $check_entry = DB::table($username)->where('Item', '=', $itemid)->first();
        if(is_null($check_entry)){  
            //$hunits = DB::table($username)->where('Item', $itemid)->select('units')->first(); 
            //$hunits=(is_null($hunits))?0:$hunits->units; 
            //DB::table($username)->where('Item', $itemid)->update(['units' => (int)$hunits + $units]);


            $hunits = DB::table($username)->where('Item', $itemid)->select('units')->get();
            DB::table($username)->where('Item', $itemid)->update(['units' => (int)$hunits + $units]);
        }
        else{
            DB::table($username)->insert(['Item' => $itemid, 'units' => $units]);
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "Zu wenig Geld auf dem Kontostand!";
    }

}
```